# How to create a Debian sid chroot from Arch Linux?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, debootstrap

I would like to create a Debian sid chroot from my Arch Linux system. I have installed debootstrap from the community repository with pacman. Then I ran:

```
# debootstrap sid $MY_CHROOT http://debian.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/debian/
```

based on the [Debian Wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) on this matter. Then what I got was almost an immediate (~5 seconds) exiting of the command with the output:

```
W: Cannot check Release signature; keyring file not available /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
I: Retrieving InRelease
```

To me this seems to indicate that debootstrap failed and did very little. On the off chance this warning was the cause of the subsequent error I ran the command again with the option `--no-check-gpg` and yet again it failed with the same output, except without the `W: Cannot...` line. Based on [this Arch Linux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226328) I installed debian-archive-keyring with pacman. Then I re-ran the original debootstrap command and it returned:

```
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 126C0D24BD8A2942CC7DF8AC7638D0442B90D010)
```

and exited within 5 seconds again. As expected running with `--no-check-gpg` did nothing but silence the signature messages.